# OpenCV HOG and SVM implementation

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, svm, training-data

I am trying to use HOG and SVM methods to find the person walks under the camera. I am working with OpenCV [train_HOG](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/train_HOG.cpp) example. I changed `Size( 96, 160 )` to `Size( 240, 240 )` in lines 433 437 438 and 442 because the size of the video is (240x240).

I use INRIA dataset to negative samples and get frames with walking person from the video as positive samples.

After running the train_HOG.cpp, I got no error. The problem is that when I give the video as an input for `test_it()` function, It couldn't find the same person walking around.

What is the problem here?

I have 100 positive sample. Is it too few? Or Is the problem about default HOG and SVM parameters? (because I didn't change any parameters) Or something else?

Example Pos sample:

[image]

P.S : It can be done with background subtraction but want to use HOG and SVM.

Comment: maybe not your main problem, but you shouldnt compute the hog descriptor of the whole image. Instead train the minimum size you want to detect (maybe 100x100?). The HoG detector uses a multiscale sliding-wi dow detection afterwards. Be aware too  that this kind of HoG is not rorational invariant.

Comment: what I meant is that you have to crop the positive samples to only hold the person CENTERED with some little  background left around.

Comment: @mica That was my problem. I fixed it with cropping the person as 120x120 images and it worked. Thank you

Comment: nice to hear. I would like it if you write your own detailed answer and post some of the cropped positive samples so that anyone else could find help within this posting :)